# Locking width and height along with orientation lock in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, orientation, firefox-os

I am developing an app for Firefox OS which should always work in portrait view so I locked the orientation by using

```
screen.mozLockOrientation("portrait");
```

It works well

But when I rotate the device though the orientation is always portrait the width and height property does not remain the same. There are certain divisions in my app for which the width and height is decided by javascript,  based on width and height of the screen. The function to decide the size of divisions is run at app start and when I keep the phone rotated(landscape) during startup the height is taken as width and vice-versa. How can I lock width and height property of screen along with orientation lock?

Will I need to write a function which should check the device orientation first and then decide which one is the correct width and height based on orientation? Or is there an alternate way to lock the width and height properties like orientation lock?

The only way I found is a hack as shown

```
var widthToUse,heightToUse;
if(screen.width < screen.height){
widthToUse=screen.width;
heightToUse=screen.height;
}
else{
widthToUse=screen.height;
heightToUse=screen.width;
}
```

But this is only a hack. Isn't there any existing way to lock the width and height properties along with orientation lock?

Answer (score 0):

use 
   `"orientation": "portrait-primary"`
 in manifest.webapp file which makes the screen orientation to portrait permanently.